# Why shows "404 Not found Not found" when I run Google cloud endpoints into physical device in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to run google cloud endpoints backend into physical device. When I run in emulator it works and show message in toast properly. But when i connect physical device and change code part accordingly github link of hello Endpoints then it not work. Where I goes wrong please help me. 
Here is my codes :

1 MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new EndpointsAsyncTask().execute(new Pair<Context, String>(this, "Endpoint ON"));
    }
}
```

2. EndpointsAsyncTask.java
   public class EndpointsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask, Void, String> {
       private static MyApi myApiService = null;
       private Context context;

   ```
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(Pair<Context, String>... params) {
       if(myApiService == null) {

           MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                   .setRootUrl("https://android-app-backend.appspot.com/_ah/api/");


           myApiService = builder.build();
       }

       context = params[0].first;
       String name = params[0].second;

       try {
           return myApiService.sayHi(name).execute().getData();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           return e.getMessage();
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   ```

   }
3. build.gradle file of backend module

   buildscript {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.34'
       }
   }

   repositories {
       jcenter();
   }

   apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'war'
   apply plugin: 'appengine'

   sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
   targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

   dependencies {
       appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.34'
       compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.34'
       compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.34'
       compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
   }

   appengine {
       downloadSdk = true
       appcfg {
           oauth2 = true
       }

   ```
   endpoints {
       getClientLibsOnBuild = true
       getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
   }
   httpAddress = "0.0.0.0"
   ```

   }
4. manifest

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
       <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
   ```

Comment: are you trying to run a physical device against your endpoints backend running locally or on Google App Engine?  Your code snippet shows that your root url is 'android-app-backend.appspot.com'. That's the placeholder in the code but to hit your remote backend it should have your GCP project id instead of 'android-app-backend'.  Assuming that you've deployed.

Comment: I solve it. to adding my app id. Thanks :)